# What ubuntu flavour i can install in this low end machine

Tags: windows, low-power

My 13 year old brother has a notebook with an intel core duo at 1.83GHz and 2.50gb of ram.

As his computer is getting very slow(it has windows 7) he asked me to install linux in his machine as he saw mine and thinked that it will run better in his computer, As it would be his first time using linux, he is looking for a windows-like desktop. He only uses his computer for a few games(Minecraft, transformice), checking his email and some web browsing I was wondering what  will suit him best.
Sorry for the bad english and for the duplicated post but I couldnt find any good answer

EDIT: One more question, is worth using a x64 OS in that machine?

Comment: I flagged this question as a duplicate, but to make it simpler, I would recommend Lubuntu.  I don't know that the 64 bit version will make your computer any quicker, or even run on the computer as I am not families with the processor in it.

Comment: Lubuntu puts a _lot_ more stress on my computer than gnome-session-fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing ubuntu 14.10 the 32 bit version and using cinnamon

I used this link for installing cinnamon: http://www.tubuntux.com/2014/11/instalar-cinnamon-24-en-ubuntu-1410.html
Is in spanish, the commands are

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Thanks to all who answered

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently running 64 bit 14.04 on a core duo laptop and Gnome is very quick and responsive. The laptop has intel integrated graphics, 3 gigs of RAM.
What really makes the change from usable to quick is the addition of an SSD which nowadays only sets you back about $40.

Comment: I have an alienware desktop from 2014 and unity is slow for me, 4 core at 3.5 ghz overclocked to 3.9 ghz. 8 gb ram, and a $250 graphics card. It's all about that computer in specific.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04, install gnome-fallback. 
After installing stock ubuntu, log in and open the terminal. Type or copy and paste
`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`
let it work, log out and click this
[image: img1]
[image: img2]
select gnome fallback (metacity)
Metacity is 2d and easier on the processor, compiz uses more 3d rendering.
log in and
`sudo apt-get remove unity`

Comment: Although this is a 100% correct answer, it is 100% useless to a reputation 13 user...  He will not know what this means.  If you flesh this answer out a bit, he will understand better!  ;-)

Comment: There's no link. I will edit to include full installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you install Xubuntu Utopic Unicorn 32 bits.

In at least three partitions, /, /home, swap.

ftp://ftp.free.fr/mirrors/ftp.xubuntu.com/releases/14.10/release/xubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso